# Getting the number of occurrences for each combination

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, transform

I have a long dataframe that looks something similar to the following:

```
       ID      Type   Price
0      1        A       230
1      2        B       150
2      1        B       180
3      3        A       280
4      4        A       222
5      2        B       124
6      1        A       221
```

I want to count the number of occurrences for each combination of Type, depending on ID, while also getting the mean price for the each combination.

I want the following:

```
       Combinaton   Counts   Mean Price
0    [2x A, 1x B]       1        210,33 
1      [2x B]           1        137
2      [1x A]           2        251
```

I've tried .value_counts(), groupby, transforming columns, etc.. but nothing seems to get what I want. Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: You are trying to do a zillion things at once. Try doing one thing per time.

Comment: I've actually tried multiple things but in the end I can't realy get the result I want. Starting to think is not possible..

Comment: @Numbermind  Have your problem been solved ?   Does any of the answers here helpful to you ?  Please let us know if any clarification of the answers required.  If any of them help solve your problem, please accept the one that you find best and also upvote the answer(s) you find helpful.

Comment: @Numbermind  FYI, we got serial downvotes for both question and all answers because recently there's someone who do so for questions not showing attempted works or codes on trying to solve it by yourself.  Although you mentioned you tried a lot but probably the downvoter didn't see that.  So, there's not related to the quality of the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Perform two `groupby` operations, making sure the first aggregation on `Type` results in a hashable object like a tuple:

```py
df['Counts'] = np.zeros(len(df))

df = df.groupby('ID').aggregate({'Type':tuple, 'Price':'mean', 'Counts': 'count'})

print(df.groupby('Type').aggregate({'Counts':'count', 'Price': 'mean'}).reset_index())
```

Which results in:

```
        Type  Counts      Price
0       (A,)      2  251.000000
1  (A, B, A)      1  210.333333
2     (B, B)      1  137.000000
```